# Cannot find private key.pem after using openssl

Tags: linux, authentication, openssl, amazon-sagemaker, private-key

**[problem]**

I generated a private key with the following cmd

```
openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -out rsa_key.pem –nocrypt
pkcs8: Use -help for summary.
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
................+++++
...........................................+++++
```

e is 65537 (0x010001)

but I cannot find where is this key, so I tried the following 2 steps.

**[what i tried]**

1. Use `sudo find / -name 'rsa_key.pem'`, and I got Permission denied error.
2. Checked the openssl folder location using `openssl version -d`, I got `OPENSSLDIR: "/opt/conda/ssl"` under this folder I only see the following files:

   cacert.pem
   cert.pem
   ct_log_list.cnf
   ct_log_list.cnf.dist
   misc
   openssl.cnf
   openssl.cnf.dist
3. Ignore this problem, go to generate public using `openssl rsa -in rsa_key.pem -pubout -out rsa_key.pub`, and I got an error.

Error message

```
Can't open rsa_key.pem for reading, No such file or directory
139653660292096:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or 
directory:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('rsa_key.pem','r')
139653660292096:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
unable to load Private Key
```

I want to know how can I fix this issue, where can I find the rsa_key.pem generated?

**[Addition]**

- If I generate key using `openssl genrsa -out snowflake_key 4096`,
  then I will find it in the current working directory
- If I generate key using `$ openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -out rsa_key.p8 -nocrypt`, then I can find it in the current working directory as well.

Comment: It is in the current working directory, surely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
cd /tmp
openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -out rsa_key.pem
openssl rsa -in rsa_key.pem -pubout -out rsa_key.pub
```

Comment: I tried but it ask me to enter a Enter Encryption Password, what is this for ?

Comment: That's the passphrase for the private key. You can type Enter if you don't need one.

Comment: thanks so much, it works, and do you have any idea the reason why in my original cmd, with "-inform PEM -out rsa_key.pem –nocrypt " it did not work ?

Comment: Another question, when I copy the public key from the file, it also copied the space between each line, should I remove this space before I added them into my user ?

Comment: It seems `–nocrypt` causes problem. There should be no spaces in the public key.

Answer (score 0):

Ssh keys are generally kept under `~/.ssh/` directory.
While using openssl ssh keys are generated in the current working directory unless you specify explicit path.
If you generate ssh keys using `ssh-keygen` then by default the keys would be placed in `~/.ssh/` directory but it does give you a choice to choose destination directory.

Comment: I do not see the key file after using ls ~/.ssh/

Comment: Normally openssl commands generate outputs in the same directory where they are run, I've done it several times and never had this problem. Can you paste the complete outputs of the commands you're running ?

Comment: I added some other information in the question, and normally the output I pasted are the complete ones. I can find it when the it is .p8 but not .pem